# JSON Parse Error : Unexpected Identifier "Undefined"(React Native)

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use Async storage to store two Text Input values stored as an object and pass it to a different view where they'll be displayed on a button press.

As mentioned in other StackOverflow posts I've used JSON.parse and JSON.stringify to pass the object as JSON data, still for some reason I;m getting the error JSON Parse Error: Unexpected Identifier "Undefined"(React Native)

#### Add Data

```
class AddData extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        text1: '' ,
        text2: ''

    };
}
  render() {
      function BtnPress() {
          alert('Hi')
      }
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <TextInput
          style={{height: 40,width:200}}
          onChangeText={(text1) => this.setState({input1: text1})}
            />
          <TextInput
          style={{height: 40,width:200}}
          onChangeText={(text2) => this.setState({input2: text2})}
            />
            <Button
            onPress={() => {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({
                    name:'Rohit',
                    email: 'rohitgird12gmail.com'
                }));
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {});
            }}
            title="Submit"
/>


      </View>


    );
  }
}
```

#### View to Display Data

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {

         displayName = async ()=> {
            try {
              const myArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
              if (myArray !== null) {
                alert(JSON.parse(myArray.name));
              }
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error)
            }
        }
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Button
      onPress={this.displayName}
      title="Get Data"
/>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `const myArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');` is returning `undefined` while you defended yourself from `null` only, which is not sufficient here.

Antoher possible problem lies here : `JSON.parse(myArray.name)`. Are you sure it's not supposed to be `JSON.parse(myArray).name`?

Comment: You are right. It should be JSON.parse(myArray).name instead of JSON.parse(myArray.name)